# Is $\overline{B_1((1,0))}\cup B_1((-1,0))$ connected? Is it path connected?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness, path-connected

I'm trying to solve a question which asks me to let $B_1(p)$ denote the unit ball around $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I'm supposed to decide whether $\overline{B_1((1,0))}\cup B_1((-1,0))$ is connected and/or path connected?

On the one hand I feel like it should be disconnected because I can't see how you can get two non-empty disjoint open sets whose union is the whole set, but on the other hand I think it should be path connected since you could go from any point in $\overline{B_1((1,0))}$ to $(0,0)$ and then presumably into $B_1((-1,0))$ continuously because it gets arbitrarily close to $(0,0)$, and path-connectedness implies connectedness.

I'd appreciate it if you could tell me where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your second thought is correct: that set is is path-connected because, given any two points $p$ and $q$ in it, you can go from $p$ to $(0,0)$ in a straight line and then from $(0,0)$ to $q$, again in a straight line, without leaving your set.

And, since it is path-connected, it is connected.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but if $p$ is in $\overline{B_{1}((1,0))}$ and $q$ is in $B_{1}((-1,0))$, then I can explicitly construct a path from $p$ to $(0,0)$ because its closed, but I don't see how one can find a path from $(0,0)$ to $q$, given $(0,0)$ does not actually lie in $B_{1}((-1,0))$ because its open.

Comment: @Batrachotoxin I never said that the path lies on $B_1\bigl((-1,0))$, only that it lies on $B_1\bigl((-1,0))\cup\overline{B_1\bigl((1,0)\bigr)}$.

Comment: Oh! Makes sense, thankyou!!